# How to enable the Tab key to "leave / jump out" the cursor from closing ""{}[]()'' in Eclipse Neon with PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, editor, eclipse-pdt

I'm use to press the Tab key to "leave / jump out" from closing caracteres like ""[]''{}():

```
The cursor = |
```

I press " key:

```
 echo "|"
```

so I press the Tab key:

```
echo ""|
```

It works fine on Aptana Studio that was discontinued :/. I am trying to move to eclipse with PDT, but it is annoying. On eclipse this command works only in Javascript Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its a bug, report it on project Bugzilla - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT

Comment: I'm trying to do this. But I can't get an account in eclipse forum site.